# How can I force my Ubuntu Server to use the correct ethernet port (interface)

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, netplan, routing

I have an Ubuntu Server running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

It has two ethernet ports, `enp3s0` and `enxf8e43b557271`.

`enxf8e43b557271` is much faster, so I want to use that by default, but, if it goes down for some reason, I want to fallback to `enp3s0`.

I understand the way to do this is with the route metric.

I have a single netplan configuration file at `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.0.142/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1]
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.0.1
        metric: 200
    enxf8e43b557271:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.0.4/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.0.1
        metric: 0
  version: 2
```

I have set `enp3s0` to a higher metric, so I would expect it to be a lower priority.

However, when I run `route -n` it doesn't seem to have worked:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enxf8e43b557271
10.40.27.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp3s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enxf8e43b557271
```

and `enp3s0` still has the default route with a metric of 0.

And when I download a large test file I see that it uses the slower connection (via monitoring on my switch):

[image: Image showing 100MBit connection being used for download, not the Gigabit connection]

If I physically unplug the `enp3s0` ethernet cable it will fallback and use the `enxf8e43b557271` - I just want the fallback to be the other way round!

I've tried splitting the config into two:

```
ls -l /etc/netplan/
-rw------- 1 root root 491 Dec 28 14:46 00-installer-config.yaml
-rw------- 1 root root 208 Dec 28 14:47 99-enxf8e43b557271-config.yaml
```

```
00-installer-config.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.0.142/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1]
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.0.1
        metric: 200
  version: 2
```

```
99-enxf8e43b557271-config.yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    enxf8e43b557271:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.0.4/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.0.1
        metric: 0
```

Comment: You might want to do a bond as an active-backup instead of two separate interfaces with different IPs. See https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/#how-to-configure-interface-bonding

Comment: @Terrance Please post that as an answer - it looks promising!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bonding the NICs should probably be the better choice with them set as active-backup meaning that you can have a primary NIC and if it fails it will switch over to the secondary automatically.  Plus, you only need to set 1 IP address as it will fail over the IP to the secondary NIC as well so that your server doesn't go offline or unreachable.

Based on [Netplan | Read the docs](https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/#how-to-configure-interface-bonding) you could do the following (assuming your interfaces were named `eth0` and `eth1`):

```yaml
network:
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0: # fast
      dhcp4: no
    eth1: # slow
      dhcp4: no
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: no
      interfaces:
        - eth0
        - eth1
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.4/24
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.0.1
        metric: 0
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 1.0.0.1
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        primary: eth0
        mii-monitor-interval: 1 # milliseconds
  version: 2
```

You can change the names / nameservers and routes as needed for your configuration

Comment: Fantastic - this (eventually) worked! I had extra challenges, notably that my faster NIC is a USB, and seems to change its logical name sometimes. I've set them to be renamed based on driver (to `eth0` and `eth1`). I also had a problem with pivpn, where it didn't set the iptables rules correctly for the bond0 interface on install, I had to use `pivpn -d` to fix it. All working now, with failover when the fast connection is lost: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7mfB.png. My full netplan is https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NBD92qTbNH/. Thanks for the help!